# Using Twitter Stream API with Python

Tags: python, api, twitter, python-requests

Thank you in advanced! I deleted my OAuth information and this code worked for the non-streaming component of the Twitter API. I know want a continuous session and I am not doing that. How do I create one? I am using Python 3.3.2 and would prefer not to use a library like tweepy.

```
import requests
import json
import time
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

twitter = OAuth1Session('',client_secret='',resource_owner_key='',resource_owner_secret='')


url = 'https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1/user.json'
r = twitter.get(url)
data = json.loads(r.text)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [the OAuth1Session sourcecode](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/blob/d9191b409a1d6a9bf3990f0f084e7a27a27ade3f/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_session.py), the class inherits from [requests.Session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#sessionapi).

You can use [`twitter.get(url, stream=True)`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Session.get), as described in [the official requests streaming example](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-requests).

The return value of `twitter.get(...)` then exposes a generator interface, so you can iterate over the lines. Note, however, that you manually have to separate the JSON records in the stream and pass them to [`json.loads()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) one-by-one.